# Find elements and subset double array - matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to find the elements [3 4] and [14 12] in the double array but I get strange result, why? Furthermore, how can I subset the data between them?

Code:

```
clc;
clear;
M = [ 1 2; 3 4; 8 2; 4 5; 7 8; 1 5; 2 7; 6 8; 9 4; 3 9; 10 11; 12 13; 14 12; 45 67; 49 50; 55 67; 44 77; 66 88] 
idx1= find(M==[3 4])
idx2= find(M==[14 12])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [ismember function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html#d117e765588) to do a comparation row by row.

```
clc; clear;
M = [ 1 2; 3 4; 8 2; 4 5; 7 8; 1 5; 2 7; 6 8; 9 4; 3 9; 10 11; 12 13; 14 12; 45 67; 49 50; 55 67; 44 77; 66 88];
idx1 = find(ismember(M,[3 4],'rows'))
idx2 = find(ismember(M,[14 12],'rows'))
```

`idx1` and `idx2` will have the row number.